# Increase indentation size of tabs in Quilljs

Tags: quill

I'm using [Quill.js](https://github.com/quilljs/quill) as a rich text editor. When you hit <kbd>TAB</kbd> it inserts a `\t` tab character into the Quill Delta. On the editor, this Delta is converted to HTML, (that conversion seems to happen in this [`convertHTML()`](https://github.com/quilljs/quill/blob/d4a4f02f587a366adb9a00f134705027eb76900c/core/editor.js#L263) method) and that `\t` character is converted to 4 spaces. I would like to customize my Quill editor, however, to change the number of spaces it outputs for a `\t` character to, for example, 6.

I believed at first I could accomplish this through the [Keyboard Module](https://quilljs.com/docs/modules/keyboard/), however this is simply for controlling keybindings which affects the Delta data structure, not the HTML output for the editor. I considered briefly using the Keyboard Module to override the <kbd>TAB</kbd> keybinding to insert multiple `\t` characters, but that is only a partial solution as I want to be able to allow the user to specify their own number of spaces that constitutes a tab, and multiple `\t` characters merely lets me do it in increments of 4 spaces. I've combed the docs as well as issues on the GitHub project and can't find anything that mentions letting me customize that output. I'm hoping this is even possible and perhaps someone else out there has already done this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use css tab-size:

```
.ql-editor {
  tab-size: 20;
  -moz-tab-size: 20;
  -o-tab-size:  20;
 }
```

Demo:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qvoeJm

Comment: Assumed this would be part of the actual HTML conversion. Good find.